# Find all solutions to $\sin(z+i)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So basically for this question I tried going about it two different ways. The first way I used the identity:

$$\sin(z)=\frac{(e)^{iz}-e^{-iz}} {2i}$$

and applying it to z+i as in a translation to +i.

I got $$\sin(z+i)=\frac{(e)^{i(z+i)}-e^{-i(z+i)}} {2i}$$

$$=\frac{(e)^{iz-1}-e^{-iz+1}} {2i}$$

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or not however. As I also tried this second approach with the basic formula of (knowing $z=x+iy$):

$\sin(z)=\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)$

$=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$

But then again I need to take into considerations the translation of the $i$. But wouldn't that make my equations into something messy like:

$\sin(z+i)=\sin(x+i(y+1))=\sin(x)\cos(i(y+1))+\cos(x)\sin(i(y+1))$

Is there an identity I'm missing here? I believe this second method I have laid out is the better way to go about this one. But I am not sure.

Comment: Both methods work, you just have to continue either of them. What is your question here?

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is $$ z+i=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$
$$
z=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i
$$

this comes from:
$$
\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=1
$$
that, with $u=e^{ix}$, becomes:

$u^2-2iu-1=0$

$(u-i)^2=0$

$u=i$

so we have
$e^{ix}=i $ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Comment: It's easy to say that all the real solution of $\sin(z)=1$ are $z=\pi/2+2k\pi$, but it is less standard that these are the only *complex* solutions.  Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: I added something....:)

Comment: And for that, you get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You found $\dfrac{(e)^{iz-1}-e^{-iz+1}} {2i}=1$ with $e^{iz}=w$ then $\dfrac{w}{e}-\dfrac{e}{w}=2i$ or $w^2-2iew-e^2=0$ and $(w-ie)^2=0$ means $e^{iz}=ie$ and
$$iz=\ln|ie|+i(2k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2})$$
so
$$\color{blue}{z=-i+2k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z= x+iy$. Then,

$$\sin (z+1)= \frac{e^{iz-1} - e^{-iz+1}}{2i} = 1 \Longrightarrow e^{iz-1} - e^{-iz+1} = 2i$$

$$e^{iz-1} - e^{-iz+1}= e^{-(y+1)+xi} - e^{(y+1)-xi}= e^{-(y+1)} (\cos (x) + i \sin (x)) - e^{(y+1)} (\cos (-x)+i \sin (-x) ) = e^{-(y+1)} (\cos (x) + i \sin (x)) - e^{(y+1)} (\cos(x)- i \sin (x) )= 2i \Longrightarrow \cos (x) (e^{-(y+1)}-e^{y+1}) =0$$

Separate in cases. First, suppose $e^{-(y+1)}-e^{y+1}=0$.

$$e^{-(y+1)}-e^{y+1}=0 \Longrightarrow -(y+1)= y+1 \Longrightarrow y= -1$$

$$\sin (x) (e^{-(y+1)}+e^{y+1} )= 2 \Longrightarrow \sin(x) = \frac{2}{e^{-(y+1)}+e^{y+1}}= \frac{2}{1+1}=1 \Longrightarrow x = 2 \pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

We then get the first solution: $z= (2 \pi k+ \frac{\pi}{2})-i$.

Now, suppose it was $\cos (x) =0$. Then $sin(x)=1 \lor \sin(x)=-1$. Suppose $\sin (x)= 1$. Then, $x= \frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi k$.

$$\sin (x) (e^{-(y+1)}+e^{y+1} )= 2 \Longrightarrow (e ^ {y+1})^2-2(e^{y+1})+1= (e^{y+1}-1)^2=0 \Longrightarrow y=-1$$

This solution was included in the case before.

Suppose $\cos (x) = 0$ and $\sin (x) = -1 $. Then, $x=\frac{3 \pi}{2}+ 2 \pi k$.

$$\sin (x) (e^{-(y+1)}+e^{y+1} )= 2 \Longrightarrow e^{-(y+1)}+e^{y+1} = -2$$

Which isn't possible because the exponential function is always positive (for real exponent).

Then, the only solutions are of the form $z= (2 \pi k+ \frac{\pi}{2})-i$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.